# Heroku Nodejs vs Vercel Nodejs

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io, vercel

I am having a server hosted in Heroku. Also, the client side(React) is hosted in Vercel. This combination works perfectly ! But, out of my curiosity, I tried to host the server-side script in Vercel. Then, when I try to connect to the Vercel-hosted-server, the client side is returning this error `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://socketio-vercel.vercel.app/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NVeP_Ax' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` (I am testing in localhost:3000 )

Server-side code (both are same in Heroku and Vercel) ->

```
"use strict";

const express = require("express");
const socketIO = require("socket.io");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const INDEX = "/index.html";

const server = express()
  .use((req, res) => res.sendFile(INDEX, { root: __dirname }))
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`));

const io = socketIO(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("Client connected");
  socket.on("disconnect", () => console.log("Client disconnected"));
});

setInterval(() => io.emit("time", new Date().toTimeString()), 1000);
```

Client-side code (if server is hosted with Heroku) (Working) ->

```
useEffect(() => {
if (shouldStart) {
  axios.get("api/sync").then((response) => {
    setMessages(response.data);
    const socket = io("wss://radiant-mountain-09008.herokuapp.com");
    socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("connected"); // "G5p5..."
    });
    socket.on("time", (msg) => {
      console.log(msg);
    });
  });
}
}, [shouldStart]);
```

Client-side code (if server is hosted with Vercel) ->

```
useEffect(() => {
if (shouldStart) {
  axios.get("api/sync").then((response) => {
    setMessages(response.data);
    const socket = io("wss://socketio-vercel.vercel.app");
    socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("connected"); // "G5p5..."
    });
    socket.on("time", (msg) => {
      console.log(msg);
    });
  });
}
}, []);
```

Any idea why is this happening ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far I know vercel supports serverless function only. You can't use any socket, websocket Libraries. You can learn more details in this official [link](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions/4536) from their github. I hope this will help. Good luck